# WSO2 api manager fails (405 - Method Not Allowed) after signing-in to /store

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, ibm-api-management

I [downloaded](https://wso2.com/api-management/download-thank-you/?type=binary) and run wso2 API Manager (version **wso2am-3.0.0**). I followed the [quick start guide](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Quick+Start+Guide) and stuck on the 6th step:

> Sign in to the API Store (https://localhost:9443/store) with the 
>   admin/admin  credentials and click on the PizzaShackAPI API.

After signing-in i get the following error (displayed in the browser):

```
Error 405 - Method Not Allowed
```

Why does this message appear? Did I miss something in the configuration?

Comment: what is the APIM version you downloaded ? It it APIM 3.0.0 ? Or 2.6.0 as per the docs you are following ?

Comment: @naoko I downloaded wso2am-3.0.0.zip

Comment: in APIM 3.0.0 you have to use /devportal. Store app has been renamed to devportal. And also please follow the docs at https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/ for latest APIM 3.0 version

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With APIM 3.0.0, the store app is removed. Please try https://localhost:9443/devportal